# gaps in sequence, join on relative position

Tags: mysql, sql, join

My first time asking a questions. Apologize in advance if you have to click on image to get sample data and what I'm looking for. I couldn't get the format to look right with just text.

[Image with sample data and what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7hSn.png)

Edit: Maybe this will help...

My data is actually just strings delimited by '|' and ','. Each order has 2 sides and a bunch of providers and prices. The providers ordered by price descending.

order1|side=0|0,price1,provider1|1,price2,provider2|2,price3,provider1
order1|side=1|0,price4,provider2|1,price5,provider1|2,price6,provider1

So provider1 gave best price (price1) on side0 and worst price (price3) on side0. Provider1 also gave second best price on side1 and worst price on side1. I wanted to pair price1 with price5 and price3 with price6 and get a difference.

To start I parsed the string into 2 tables with columns:

Table1

Order|Side|Level|Provider|Price

1.......|0.....|0.......|1...........|1.......

1.......|0.....|1.......|2...........|2.......

1.......|0.....|2.......|1...........|3.......

Table2

Order|Side|Level|Provider|Price

1.......|1.....|0.......|2...........|4.......

1.......|1.....|1.......|1...........|5.......

1.......|1.....|2.......|1...........|6.......

I want to compare provider1's first price on side0 with provider1's first price on side1 regardless of level. And provider1's second price on side0 with provider1's second price on side1 regardless of level. And so forth for as long as I can pair provider1's prices on both sides.

My image is select order, level, price from table1 where provider=1;
and select order, level, price from table2 where provider=1;

In production, I will have more than 1 order and side 0 and 1 have uneven number of prices. So if provider1 gave 1 price on side0 and 3 on side1, I only want to compare side0 price with best side1 price.

Edit 2: Solution found

Apparently what I wanted is called auto increment by group as described in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html.

create table3
(order int(10) unisgned, id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, price double, primary key (order,id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

insert into table3 (order, price) as (select order, price from table1 where provider=1);

repeat for other table, join on order, id.

Comment: The image is not enough. Pls say something about what do you want.

Comment: Do you want top 3 records from both tables?

Comment: @DylanSu Does this help?

Comment: @Suyash Does this help?

Comment: Post a solution. pls check if it is what you expect. @JoshZhou

Answer (score 0):

It is really hard to understand the scenario. Based on your sample data, here comes the solution.

SQL:

```
-- Prepare data, just for demo
create table table1(id int auto_increment primary key, `order` int, var int, data char(20));
create table table2(id int auto_increment primary key, `order` int, var2 int, data2 char(20));
insert into table1(`order`, var, data) values
(1,1,'x'),
(1,3,'y'),
(1,5,'z');
insert into table2(`order`, var2, data2) values
(1,1,'a'),
(1,2,'b'),
(1,6,'c'),
(1,7,'d');
select * from table1;
select * from table2;

-- Process of reporting
SET @rownum1:=0; 
SET @rownum2:=0; 
SELECT t1.order, t1.var, t2.var2, t1.data, t2.data2
FROM 
    (SELECT *, @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum FROM table1) t1, 
    (SELECT *, @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 AS rownum FROM table2) t2
WHERE t1.rownum = t2.rownum AND 
    t1.`order` = 1 AND
    t2.`order` = 1;
```

Output:

```
mysql> select * from table1;
+----+-------+------+------+
| id | order | var  | data |
+----+-------+------+------+
|  1 |     1 |    1 | x    |
|  2 |     1 |    3 | y    |
|  3 |     1 |    5 | z    |
+----+-------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2;
+----+-------+------+-------+
| id | order | var2 | data2 |
+----+-------+------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |    1 | a     |
|  2 |     1 |    2 | b     |
|  3 |     1 |    6 | c     |
|  4 |     1 |    7 | d     |
+----+-------+------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
mysql> -- Process of reporting
mysql> SET @rownum1:=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @rownum2:=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT t1.order, t1.var, t2.var2, t1.data, t2.data2
    -> FROM
    -> (SELECT *, @rownum1:=@rownum1+1 AS rownum FROM table1) t1,
    -> (SELECT *, @rownum2:=@rownum2+1 AS rownum FROM table2) t2
    -> WHERE t1.rownum = t2.rownum AND
    -> t1.`order` = 1 AND
    -> t2.`order` = 1;
+-------+------+------+------+-------+
| order | var  | var2 | data | data2 |
+-------+------+------+------+-------+
|     1 |    1 |    1 | x    | a     |
|     1 |    3 |    2 | y    | b     |
|     1 |    5 |    6 | z    | c     |
+-------+------+------+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks! Not exactly the answer I needed but gave me the key words to search. Auto increment by group was my answer.